# Add a field to an existing model

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-forms

I want to add a created_at field to my ClientUploads model.  It looks like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUploads(models.Model):

    client = models.OneToOneField(Client)
    #created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        name = "uploads/%s/%s" % (self.client.company, filename)
        return name

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")
```

But when I add the created_at and then submit the form I get the error that the column doesn't exist.  I tried renaming the model, and doing a migrate to erase the old one and create another model where created_at would exist from the start but I still got the same error.  How can I add this field?  Or is there already such a field?  Regardless I need to have a created_at field and I can't find out how to add it without breaking the form.

Comment: You don't need to rename the model, but you do need to create and run migrations.

Comment: I did run the migrations it didn't detect the change for some reason.  makemigrations said no changes detected, and migrate said the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted databases and then ran makemigrations and migrate and createsuperuser, and reentered the data from scratch.  I tried flush, didn't work. `echo "" > dbfile` also works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted, you have the created_at field commented out. You'll need to uncomment that line (remove the `#` at the front) and then run `manage.py makemigrations`, and then `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Commented out bc i wasnt working it is now but deleting db and recreating